# using href in jsx onclick button

Tags: html

I have a button in my website, which should open new tab in the browser and redirect to some domain, although i can't seem to get it working, could I get help?
What i've tried so far.

```
<div className="width-100p dis-flex dis-flex-middle dis-flex-center"><span><button className="btn btn-primary integration-connect-btn"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"></a>Connect</button></span></div>
```

From my point of view, this looks correct, could I get help?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because it is not allowed by HTML5. A button can not contain interactive content.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

You can add an `onClick` event handler to the button to make it redirect to http://www.google.com. Note that the following code snippet does not work because it is executed inside an `iframe` whose sandbox attribute does not allow popups. Check the console to see the error.

```html
<div className="width-100p dis-flex dis-flex-middle dis-flex-center"><span><button className="btn btn-primary integration-connect-btn" onClick="connect()">Connect</button></span></div>
<script>
function connect(){
 var url = "http://google.com";
 window.open(url,'_blank');
}
</script>
```

Check this JSFiddle to see the above code snippet working: http://jsfiddle.net/ua9m156c/.

Alternatively, you can wrap the `a` tag inside a `div` styled to look like a `button`.

```css
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#444;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background:#DDD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.button:active {
    color:red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
div.button a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
}
div.button a:visited{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Connect</a>
</div>
```

Check this JSFiddle to see the above code snippet in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jo8Lqc15/.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to hev1's answer, just style your A element with the button classes (it looks like bootstrap classes) and remove the button wrapper, which should work fine for your needs.